# Verbose output for cmake command

Tags: cmake

I would like to know if there is any way to debug a `cmake` process that forcing the command to print mode details about how variables are getting some value. For example, I see

```
-- Boost version: 1.63.0
-- Boost version: 1.63.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   filesystem
--   timer
--   chrono
```

And I would like to know where does that version is checked and found.

I have added `set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)` in the first line of `CMakeLists.txt` prior to running `cmake ..`. However, I don't see any verbose message.

I am looking for some thing like `set -x` in bash programming.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cmake has command line options `--trace`, `--trace-expand`, and `--trace-source=some_cmake_source`

These will give you very verbose output, and if you start cmake like this:

```
$cmake --trace-expand source_dir
```

will output complete configure process, with all cmake variables replaced with their value. Since the amount of output is huge (literally) I usually redirect it into file, like this:

```
$cmake --trace-expand source_dir > trace.txt 2>&1
```

This will redirect complete output, including error messages, into the file `trace.txt`.

If you don't want output of complete configure, but one particular file, you should use `--trace-source=some-source`, like this:

```
$cmake --trace-source=FindBoost.cmake source_dir
```

will output execution of that particular file (in this case, it will show the process of searching for boost libraries)

Also, setting `CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE` variable will not help you, since it controls verbosity during the build process, not configure.

at the end, here are references to cmake documentation:

[cmake command line options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/manual/cmake.1.html)

[CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE.html)

Answer (score 3):

CMake provides `--debug-output` and `--trace` [options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#options) that can be used when running from the command line:

```
cmake --debug-output ..
```

or

```
cmake --trace ..
```

The `debug-output` option provides some high-level insight into how CMake is traversing your CMakeLists.txt file structure; this can be set from the CMake GUI also (**Options** > **Debug Output**). The `trace` option dumps CMake's processing line-by-line (likely want to redirect this output to a file). The `trace` option also comes with `trace-expand` and `trace-source=<file>` flavors, to expand CMake variables and trace only a specific file, respectively.

If you use `trace` to find a CMake file and variable of interest (e.g. a `BOOST` variable), you can also make use of [`variable_watch()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/variable_watch.html) to help monitor changes to that variable, and print messages to the screen.